# What goes in a good tag message?

Tags: version-control, tagging

There are plenty of resources on the web on how to write good commit messages, and it isn’t really all that hard.  I’d like to know what makes up a good *tag* message though.  Simply citing the summary lines of all commits since the previous tag is probably not really useful.  What do you deem a ‘quality’ tag message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I'd call a 'quality tag' would have to be fairly complete. Generally, I would consider a good tag to be short, to the point, but also explain exactly what went on, like so:

"Committed the public directory, containing the new logo (logo.png), the new stylesheet (style1.css), and with the javascript that selects checkboxes of parents if their children are checked in a hierarchical structure (checkheir.js), did some code refactoring, made it more readable, and added comments for easier comprehension -John Doe"

Comment: This one is pretty tool specific, but in subversion where tags are simply copies - it's usually good form to have something like "Tagged trunk at r65345"

Comment: So you basically suggest a short summary of all commit messages since the last tga?